# Facebook graph API returns time out exception while authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, timeout, authorization

```
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(“https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}”, strClientID, “http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html”));
```

I am using this code.

But i getting operation has timed out error.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

this is my coe

```
 getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}", strClientID, "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

            getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            getRequest.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;
            getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
            getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
            getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            //getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            //byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            //getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            //newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
            //newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
```

I am getting this error from this code

```
 getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
```

please help me as soon as possible. All the comments and replies are appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is we can use only one HttpWebResponse at a time. In my case i am using the same object in two times without any disposing and closing. That's make me the error.

So I updated my code like this.

```
 byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.

        getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        getresponse.Close();
```

This solved my error. Thanks